Delete only faces in whole scene
I m trying to script that delete all faces in my scene, but not the edges and loose edges.
I try many but still no good results.
With GUI it works like that :

Select object
Go to edit mode
Select all
Hit delete
In context menu choose faces.
That s it.
Any hunt to script this ?
Best regards, Gilles


Thank you very much, I just add active object function and iterate on all objects :
objects = bpy.context.scene.objects
for obj in objects :
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    if obj.type == "MESH":
        obj.select_set(True)
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type="FACE")
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')


Why do you need this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

The script for this process is quite easy to set up. In your Preferences, under Interface, you can activate the Python Tooltips, so that you see the python function which is called when you interact with any UI element. Using these tooltips, I basically charted the GUI method and translated it to python:
import bpy

bpy.ops.object.mode_set() # Go into Object mode in case you aren't yet

# Select all objects which are a normal mesh
objects = bpy.context.scene.objects

for obj in objects:
    obj.select_set(obj.type == "MESH")

bpy.ops.object.editmode_toggle() # Go into Edit mode
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all() # Select every mesh part
bpy.ops.mesh.delete(type="ONLY_FACE") # and delete only the faces
```

